# Multiple shaders on same mesh

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, shader

I'm trying to create a simple 3d game engine.
I can load shaders and use them but I've something more special.
I've a simple texturing shader and a lighting shader.
They are seperate shaders and I want to work them together.
However if I do texturing with this shader:

```
//Vertex
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
out vec2 TexCoord2;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = ModelViewMatrix * vec4(Position, 1.0);
    TexCoord0 = TexCoord;
}
//Fragment
in vec2 TexCoord0;
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform sampler2D texSampler;
void main() { FragColor = texture2D(texSampler, TexCoord0.st); }
```

I'm getting a textured cube mesh.
Also I want to make it lighted with point and ambient lights.
But if use the texturing program cube mesh is not being effected by point lights.
Otherwise if I use point lighting shader for cube mesh, I can't get a textured cube mesh.

I can't understand what to do. How to combine them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

This is actually touching a more complicated problem of "effect" design in video engines. Books have been written about this, so you will need more literature anyway. However...

Think about the shaders. Each of them provides *a part* of the end result you want. In essence, though, light shader uses the surface *albedo* color to calculate the light on it. The very same value that's essentially in your colour texture.

So, the thing you have to do here is use both *together*. I guess adding the sampler to the lighting shader would be simpler; simply copy the variable there, set up the uniforms on the code part, and you're good to substitute albedo in your light calculations; meaning simply multiplying the calculated light color by the texture color.

To make it work as a part of the bigger system, though... It poses a bigger problem, and might be solved by techniques such as semi-automatic shader parsing and building. You can also create different effects in different shaders and link them together into one program; that would make manual writing easier, but won't ultimately solve the problem of freely applying effects to models.

### Code code code

If you'd like a code example, [here's a per-vertex lighting/texture/fog shader I wrote quite some time ago](https://github.com/bananu7/MiniCraft/blob/master/Data/shaders/texturing_and_light.vert). It could probably be done better, but it worked for me well enough. You'll find accompanying fragment shader in the same folder. As you can see, I refactored light calculations into separate functions; these functions could be in different shader files, that would be separately compiled and linked.

To narrow it down to one line:

```
out_Color = mix(light * cubeTexture, skyColor, fogFactor);
```

### Multiple geometry passes

For completeness, moved from comments; you can use two completely separate pipelines, as long as you're willing to pay the cost of processing each vertex for each pipeline. That's going to limit in you in some ways, but in your example, you could theoretically process texturing and lighting on two separate drawcalls, and only then blend the colors from two separately rendered images.

Comment: But they're seperate shaders. One is mine and other one will be developer implemention.

Comment: @PilawyerDev the pipeline can have only one `main` for each stage. There's no simple way of doing what you want (having completely separate pipelines work together), sans passing through geometry twice, which you want to avoid most of the time. You could theoretically concatenate shaders automatically and use MRT in some clever way, but that's getting even more complicated then. If you want a fully dynamic effect system, you'd have to read more about that; it's just not a simple task you are aiming at.

Comment: One more thing to go: If I render/process scene/shaders multiple times (like making shadow-mapping) that can be a solution, am I right?

Comment: @PilawyerDev yes, at least in the simple example. If you used tesselation or geometry shaders, or even moved some things in one of the vertex stages, though, you wouldn't be able to easily combine two images. It's simply a different thing.